# How to print the number of times an element appears in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two variables, x and y, where x is a number and y is a list of numbers.

I have to define a function *count* which determines how many times x appears in y,
for instance,

`count(1,[2,1,3,1,4])`

should return 2.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

NB. I am not allowed to use the in-built count function, i.e. y.count(x).

Comment: I really wish people stopped setting assignments like this, or thinking they had any real value.

Comment: did you tried basic approach like `>>> count = 0
>>> for i in l:
...  if i == 1: count += 1
... return count`

Comment: It doesn't really have a value, no. Its purpose is not for a practical reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a generator expression and `sum` function like this

```
sum(item == x for item in y)
```

You can put that in a function, like this

```
def counter(my_list, key):
    return sum(item == key for item in my_list)

assert counter([2, 1, 3, 1, 4], 1) == 2
assert counter([2, 1, 3, 1, 4], 5) == 0
assert counter([2, 1, 3, 1, 4], 2) == 1
```

This works because, in Python booleans are subclasses of integers. So, `True` will be treated as `1` and `False` will be treated as `0`. In our case, we take each element from `my_list` and check if it is equal to the `key`. If they are equal, it evaluates to `1` otherwise `0`. Then we `sum` the entire result.

Answer (score 3):

Its already built-in to Python:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([2,1,3,1,4])[1]
2
```

If you want to do it the "long" way, use a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for i in [2,1,3,1,4]:
    d.setdefault(i, 0)
    d[i] += 1
print(d[1])  #  prints 2
```

Comment: +1 but OP specifically saying "*not* allowed to use the *in-built* count function, i.e."

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan *in-built `count`* function ;)

Comment: Burhan actually we could merge `d[i] = d.setdefault(i, 0) + 1`

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a loop:

```
def count_occurences(num, lst):
    return len([i for i in lst if i==num])

    #or return sum(1 for i in lst if i==num)

>>> print count_occurences(1, [2,1,3,1,4])
2
```